# TimeSpan of days in configuration?

Tags: c#, timespan, configurationsection

It appears that `ConfigurationElement` of `TimeSpan` can't handle values larger than 23:59:59.   Are there any workarounds?  Is subclassing `TimeSpan`, and making a new `TimeSpanValidatorAttribute` even going to work?   I need to handle timespans from a few minutes to a few days.

I'm using the following configuration section

```
[ConfigurationProperty("SequenceRolloverDOSCompare", IsRequired = true)]
[TimeSpanValidator(MinValueString = "0:0:00", MaxValueString = 10675199.02:48:05.4775807", ExcludeRange = false)]
public TimeSpan SequenceRolloverDOSCompare
{
    get
    {
        return (TimeSpan)base["SequenceRolloverDOSCompare"];
    }
}
```

with config looking like this:

```
<SequenceRolloverPolling SequenceRolloverDOSCompare="2:00:00:00"  />
```

gives `ConfigurationErrorsException : The value of the property 'SequenceRolloverDOSCompare' cannot be parsed. The error is: 2:00:00:00 is not a valid value for TimeSpan.`

or this:

```
<SequenceRolloverPolling SequenceRolloverDOSCompare="48:00:00"  />
```

gives `OverflowException : The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least one of the hours, minutes, or seconds components is outside its valid range`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the `.` separator between days and hours:

```
<SequenceRolloverPolling
    SequenceRolloverDOSCompare="2.00:00:00" />
```

The [TimeSpan format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) is defined as:

> ... [-]d.hh:mm:ss.ff, where the optional minus sign indicates a negative time interval, the d component is days, hh is hours as measured on a 24-hour clock, mm is minutes, ss is seconds, and ff  is fractions of a second.

Comment: my eyes must have glazed over

Comment: Actually the day component is not required too for me. SequenceRolloverDOSCompare="01:02:03" format is also OK.